# Existence of $G$ for $\nabla \times G=F$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> What are the necessary and sufficient conditions on functions $h,k:{\Bbb R}^2\to{\Bbb R}$ such that given any smooth $F:{\Bbb R^3}\to{\Bbb R}^3$ of the form $F=(F_1(y,z),F_2(x,z),0)$ and whose divergence is zero, there is a smooth $G:{\Bbb R}^3\to{\Bbb R}^3$ of the form $G=(G_1,G_2,0)$ such that $\nabla\times G=F$ in ${\Bbb R}^3$ and $G=(h,k,0)$ on $z=0$?

Can anyone explain what $G$ means in this problem and how the assumption $\nabla \cdot F=0$ might be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$G$ is called a vector potential for $F$, and $G_3 = 0$ is a gauge condition.
The basic existence result for vector potentials is that if $F$ is a smooth
vector field on a domain $D$ that has no "holes" (I'll leave out the technicalities of that) and $\nabla \cdot F = 0$ everywhere in $D$, then a vector potential for $F$ always exists.  Moreover, you can impose some gauge conditions ($G_3 = 0$ and a little more...).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've never seen "gauge condition" before in a multivariable calculus book. (And I )Is it something related to physics? Would you please point me to some mathematical references about this result? (Is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_potential the result you refer to?)

Comment: The result in your link is a special case of the more general result.  See e.g. Adams & Essex, "Calculus: A Complete Course" 7th edition, sec. 16.2, or Davis & Snyder, "Introduction to Vector Analysis", sec. 4.6, for the result on star-shaped domains.

Comment: If you want to see the phrase "gauge condition" in a calculus book, there's my "Calculus the Maple Way", 2nd edition, p. 230. http://books.google.com/books?id=SFPuAAAACAAJ

Answer (score 0):

if the divergence isn't zero, F can't be written as the curl of G. You can see this by calculating the divergence of the curl of G and using schwartz.

G is the vectorpotential of F.

Comment: What do you mean by "using Schwartz"?

Comment: type, supposed  to be schwarz. However, I can't find any information on it online, only in my calculus notes. It went something like "If f is from C2, then diff(diff(f(x,y),x),y)==diff(diff(f(x,y),y),x)"